# how to transform svg into 3D in three.js

Tags: svg, three.js

I am building a floor map in svg, it is a 2D map, I am wondering how can I transform this map into 3d space using the three.js.

I am wondering is there any API in three.js help me to transform / render these svg into 3D

[image]

Comment: Hello there, were you able to solve this ? Can you share your solution here ?

Comment: It would be great if you found a solution and share the code. Cheers.